# Regex for simple FEN validation

Tags: javascript, regex, chess

I'm looking to validate a chess [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string and I'm working on the Regex for it. I'm looking to implement only very simple validation. Here are the rules I'm looking to match with my regex:

- Exactly 7 "/" characters
- Start and end of the string cannot be "/"
- In between the slashes it must be either a number from 1-8 or the letters `PNBRQK` uppercase or lowercase

**Example of a match** 
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR

**Examples of non-match** 
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR`/` 
`/`pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR`/` 
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/`10`/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR 
rnbqkbnr/`Z`/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR

Currently, I have been able to implement exactly 7 "/" anywhere in the string with the following regex:

`/^(?:[^\/]*\/){7}[^\/]*$/gm`

I'm unsure how to implement the rest as RegEx is not my strong suit.

Comment: See also: [How do you know when a FEN position is legal?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/1487)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^([1-8PNBRQK]+\/){7}[1-8PNBRQK]+$/gim
```

`/gim` = **g**lobal, case **i**nsensitive, and **m**ultiline.

I got the above working on https://regexr.com/ - one of my favorite places for working out regex problems (but I know there are many other good resources online).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Suggested change: Add negative lookahead for two digit numbers. i.e. at the beginning of the regex, put `(?!.*\d{2,}.*)`

Comment: I just want to point out that without @dc-ddfe 's addition, this will match invalid input, e.g. `...ppp/18/ppp...`

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick: (passes all your tests)

```
/^(?:(?:[PNBRQK]+|[1-8])\/){7}(?:[PNBRQK]+|[1-8])$/gim
```

All you needed was to use positive matching for the characters you're after instead of "not slash". The key addition is the non-capturing group with one or more PNBRQK *or* a digit from 1-8. The same group is repeated at the end of the expression.

Oh, and I added the `i` flag for case insensitive matching.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but after looking at your answer, I see that you interpreted the rules slightly different and in looking back, the "it must be either a number from 1-8 or the letters PNBRQK uppercase or lowercase" is confusing. If your interpretation is the correct one, then yours is the correct answer; giving you an upvote either way. :)

Comment: @VicF It's not - In FEN notation it's possible to get something like `ppp1pppp` which means 3 pawns followed by an empty space followed by 4 pawns

Comment: Yeah, @dc-ddfe is right. I saw the full notation differed from what he was describing and just matched against the criteria and examples given. To be honest, chess is not my strong suit. :)

Comment: @BenjaminPenney This solution doesn't work for something like: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR`. At least in JavaScript.